# JavaFX tile map bad performance

Tags: java, javafx, game-development

I'm developing a 2D tile based game in JavaFx in college, I already have the sprites, animations, audio, menu ..., but I found a huge problem in rendering the map. On a 4GB notebook, Intel graphics card, Core i5, where any 2D Steam game works well at 60 FPS, my game runs from 27 to 31 FPS. I noticed that the precarious part is rendering the map, but I do not know why it's so slow. Here is the map rendering code:

```
// Clear Layers
    this.getLayer1GC().clearRect(0, 0, this.getLayer1GC().getCanvas().getWidth(),
                this.getLayer1GC().getCanvas().getHeight());

    this.getLayer2GC().clearRect(0, 0, this.getLayer2GC().getCanvas().getWidth(),
                this.getLayer2GC().getCanvas().getHeight());

    int index = 0;

    int tileSize = 64 * Engine.SCALE; // 128x128

    int startCol = Math.max(0, (int) (Engine.camera.xView / tileSize));

    int endCol = Math.min(this.width,
            (int) ((Engine.camera.xView + Engine.camera.wView) / tileSize) + 1);

    int startRow = Math.max(0, (int) (Engine.camera.yView / tileSize));

    int endRow = Math.min(this.height,
            (int) ((Engine.camera.yView + Engine.camera.hView) / tileSize) + 1);

    int tileX, tileY, indexLayer1, indexLayer2;

    for (int c = startCol; c < endCol; c++) {

        for (int r = startRow; r < endRow; r++) {

            // Tile Index
            index = this.tileManager.getTileIndex(c, r, this.width);

            // Tile Coordinates
            tileX = (int) (c * tileSize - Engine.camera.xView);
            tileY = (int) (r * tileSize - Engine.camera.yView);

            // Cache Tileset Images
            indexLayer1 = this.layer1.tileArray[index];
            indexLayer2 = this.layer2.tileArray[index];

            // Layer 1
            if (indexLayer1 > 0) {
                this.getLayer1GC().drawImage(this.mapTilset.tileImages[indexLayer1], 0, 0,
                        tileSize, tileSize, tileX, tileY, tileSize, tileSize);
            }

            // Layer 2
            if (indexLayer2 > 0) {
                this.getLayer2GC().drawImage(this.mapTilset.tileImages[indexLayer2], 0, 0,
                        tileSize, tileSize, tileX, tileY, tileSize, tileSize);
            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

What do you expect when you constantly erase and redraw all your images? Why don't you just use some ImageViews and then move them arround instead of constantly redrawing everything. Ideally this would just involve a coordinate shift of your image views and that can be done at almost no cost.